# Residue of Generalized Hypergeometric Functon at Nonpositive Indices for $p=3$ and $q=2$

Tags: limits, special-functions, hypergeometric-function

Is there a nice formula for the limit

$$\lim_{\gamma\to -n}\frac{{}_3F_2(a_1,a_2,a_3;b,\gamma;z)}{\Gamma(\gamma)}$$

Here, $n$ is a nonnegative integer and ${}_3F_2$ is the generalized hyper-geometric function.

I am hoping for something analogous to equation 9.101 in Gradshteyn and Ryzhik for the standard hypergeometric function where the result is in terms of a hypergeometric function.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't mean to write the limit as $b\to-n$?

Comment: Apologies, there was a typo. I did not include the argument $z$. Now, the limit should be nonzero and it should make sense to take $\gamma\to-n$.

Comment: [Wolfram functions](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric3F2/25/01/0002/) has a formula

Comment: The formula on Wolfram functions is exactly what I am looking for. However, numerical checks seem to suggest it is off by a factor of $\Gamma(b_1)$. Can anyone else back this up?